# YOURLS Short URL to Domain

Tags: yourls

Morning - I'd like to redirect my short url ie: https://sho.rt to my domain https://short.com

At the moment my sho.rt is pointing at the admin panel. Could you please advise as to how I'd redirect.

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build an index.php file that sits in the yourls top level directory.  A simple example of how to redirect using html is.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Your Site Title</title>
    <script>
      window.location.replace("https://www.yourwebsite.com");
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>If you are not automatically redirected in 5 seconds, <a href="https://www.yourwebsite.com" target="_self">Click Here</h2></a>
  </body>
</html>
```